# PayPal error. This transaction is invalid. Please return to the recipient's website to complete your transaction using their regular checkout flow

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to implement PayPal Direct payement to my website.

I get a Succes token back from PayPal when making a SetExpressCheckout call:

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2015-03-06T10:16:55Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 7d0a42f74fa6b
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 121
    [BUILD] => 15420584
    [AMT] => 125.00
    [CURRENCYCODE] => EUR
    [AVSCODE] => X
    [CVV2MATCH] => M
    [TRANSACTIONID] => 29A40018PU668530B
)
```

**The Response looks like this:**

TIMESTAMP=2015%2d03%2d06T10%3a16%3a55Z&CORRELATIONID=7d0a42f74fa6b&ACK=Success&VERSION=121&BUILD=15420584&AMT=125%2e00&CURRENCYCODE=EUR&AVSCODE=X&CVV2MATCH=M&TRANSACTIONID=29A40018PU668530B

I've tried to depercent the url in several ways to send the response back top paypal. What I'm using now is:

```
$result = rawurldecode($result);
```

**The result looks like this as depercented:** 
TIMESTAMP=2015-03-06T10:16:55Z&CORRELATIONID=7d0a42f74fa6b&ACK=Success&VERSION=121&BUILD=15420584&AMT=125.00&CURRENCYCODE=EUR&AVSCODE=X&CVV2MATCH=M&TRANSACTIONID=29A40018PU668530B

I've tried to lovercase the request with strtolower the result became like this:

**Lowercased result:**

timestamp=2015-03-06t10:31:45z&correlationid=490f48424be02&ack=success&version=121&build=15420584&amt=125.00¤cycode=eur&avscode=x&cvv2match=m&transactionid=80g4320670816912n

I've realised that strange character before cycode: ¤

When i try to send back the token with a redirect from PHP like this, (with or without the lowercased):

```
header('Location: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&'.$result);
```

I get redirected to:
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=...

Saying:

> This transaction is invalid. Please return to the recipient's website
>   to complete your transaction using their regular checkout flow. Return
>   to merchant At this time, we are unable to process your request.
>   Please return to and try another option. Test Site

Even when I'm using the not lowercased version I got the same error!

I've realized that localhost was a problem. When uploaded my site the SetExpressCheckout Token was fine.

The problem is now when i'm getting back this token:
TOKEN=EC%2d0PA6125744246545G&TIMESTAMP=2015%2d03%2d06T13%3a10%3a09Z&CORRELATIONID=10c7929423b68&ACK=Success&VERSION=121&BUILD=15640276

And sending a GetExpressCheckoutDetails request, with these parameters:

```
Array
(
    [METHOD] => GetExpressCheckoutDetails
    [USER] => ...
    [PWD] => ...
    [SIGNATURE] => ...
    [VERSION] => 121
    [TOKEN] => TOKEN=EC-0PA6125744246545G&TIMESTAMP=2015-03-06T13:10:09Z&CORRELATIONID=10c7929423b68&ACK=Success&VERSION=121&BUILD=15640276
)
```

I still get a Token error:

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2015-03-06T13:10:10Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 4ec125d8280f3
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 121
    [BUILD] => 15640276
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10410
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Invalid token
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Invalid token.
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

Thank you for helping me out on this!

Comment: That 'strange character' is &CURREN, and is there because you're decoding the entire string as a single querystring value.

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this question is over a year old, but I thought it was worth answering.

To start, the response that the token is invalid is accurate based on what you show in your array:

```
TOKEN=EC-0PA6125744246545G&TIMESTAMP=2015-03-06T13:10:09Z&CORRELATIONID=10c7929423b68&ACK=Success&VERSION=121&BUILD=15640276
```

This should stop at the ampersand (&) and as I show below, the `$response` array can be accessed like this to pass individual values into your next API request:

```
 $response["TOKEN"]; // this will ONLY return "EC-0PA6125744246545G" - remember that 
 // these tokens don't last beyond a few hours, but your next call should be 
 // a few seconds after the SetEC.
```

The resolution deals with a particular method: [http_build_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

```
// this is a method in a class that I built. Use it as needed
public function startRequest($params = array()){
    // this creates a handle to use later to add the request parameters to the curl call
    $request = http_build_query($params);

    $ch = curl_init();

    // cURL settings
    // the variable $this->_endpoint in this case points to:
    // https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp - you may be using SOAP, 
    // so URL will be different
    $curlOptions = array(
        CURLOPT_URL             => $this->_endpoint,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE         => 1,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => 2,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_POST            => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $request
    );

    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOptions);

    // send request - $response will hold the API response
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

The `$response` variable is an array response from PayPal which can be used like this:

```
$responseText = '';
foreach($response as $k=>$v){
        $responseText .= $k ."=". $v ."\r\n";
}

// log the API response (and the request) to a file - always a good idea, 
// in case you need support for issues later on.
file_put_contents(path_to_log_file, current_time . ' MST - API response: \r\n' . $responseText ."\r\n===========\r\n", FILE_APPEND);

// also, you can access each value in the $response array so that you can use them 
// in later calls like DoEC:
$response["TOKEN"];
```

Let me know if I can clarify anything further.